# How To Open Image in Picasa Photo Viewer

Tags: image, image-processing, imageview, photo-gallery, picasa

How can I open an image in Picasa Photo Viewer dynamically?

For Windows Photo Viewer I can use the following command:
`Process.Start(@"C:\MyPicture.jpg");`

Is there any way to change this so the picture opens in Picasa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Do this.

```
        string file = @"C:\Sunset.Jpg";
        ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo(file);
        pi.Arguments = Path.GetFileName(file);
        pi.UseShellExecute = true;
        pi.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
        pi.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Google\Picasa3\PicasaPhotoViewer.exe";
        pi.Verb = "OPEN";
        Process.Start(pi);
```

I hope This is Work For you.